# Format array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this array of objects (data). These are the first to indexes:

```
0: Object

granularity_time: "total"

granularity_geo: "nation"

location_code: "norge"

border: "2020"

age: "90+"

sex: "female"

year: "1900"

week: "1"

yrwk: "1900-01"

season: "1899/1900"

x: "24"

date: "1900-01-01"

n: "219"

date_of_publishing: "2022-01-12"

    tag_outcome: "death"

1: Object

granularity_time: "total"

granularity_geo: "nation"

location_code: "norge"

border: "2020"

age: "90+"

sex: "male"

year: "1900"

week: "1"

yrwk: "1900-01"

season: "1899/1900"

x: "24"

date: "1900-01-01"

n: "127"

date_of_publishing: "2022-01-12"

tag_outcome: "death"
```

Its statistics where men and woman in the same age has its own object. To index 0 is for woman age 90+, index 1 for men age 90+. Index 2 is for woman 80+, index 3 men 80+ etc.

I want to format the data so each index holds two objects, for men and woman in the same age.

Something like this:

```
const newData = [
{
  woman: data[0],
  men: data[1]
},
{
  woman: data[2],
  men: data[3]
},
{
  woman: data[4],
  men: data[5]
},
{
  woman: data[6],
  men: data[7]
},
{
  woman: data[8],
  men: data[9]
},
{
  woman: data[10],
  men: data[11]
},
{
  woman: data[12],
  men: data[13]
}

];
```

Ive tried to make a function that iterates over the data, but each entry ends up undefined:

```
const formatData = (data) => {
    const newData = [];

    data?.map((item, i) => {
      i % 2 === 0 ? newData.push({ woman: item[i], men: item[i++] }) : null;
    });

    return newData;
  };
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: _"What am I missing here?"_ - first of all, how to provide a _proper_ [mre] of your issue. Give an example of what exact input data you want to lead to the shown result, not just a vague verbal description that is still quite ambiguous.

Comment: I think you probably have misunderstood what `item` in the `map` callback actually is ...?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array.from()` and `Array.map()` to create the desired output from your original data array.

The length of the new array will be data.length / 2, and each alternate item will be assigned to either the men or women property of each element in the output array.

```js
const template = { year: 1900, location_code: 'norge' };
// Some array of input data...
const data = Array.from({length: 14}, (v,k) => ({...template, id: k, gender: ( k % 2 === 0 ? 'female':'male' )}));

const result = Array.from( { length: data.length / 2 }, (v, idx) => { 
    return { women: data[2*idx], men: data[2*idx + 1],  };
})

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the output is half of the input, it's really more of a reduce()...

```js
const data = [{ gender: "m", name: "sam" }, { gender: "f", name: "sally" }, { gender: "m", name: "allen" }, { gender: "f", name: "abby" }, { gender: "m", name: "jim" }, { gender: "f", name: "jill" }];

const newData = data.reduce((acc, obj, i) => {
  i % 2 ? acc[acc.length-1].woman = obj : acc.push({ man: obj })
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually works, but im not sure if its best practice since im just using the map to get i..

```
const formatData = (data) => {
const newData = [];
data?.map((item, i) => {
  i % 2 === 0
    ? newData.push({ woman: data[i], men: data[i + 1] })
    : null;
});
return newData;
```

};

Comment: There's no harm in this, but you're right that having map generate a side-effect and ignoring it's return value is exactly like not using map. If you want to use a functional style, then only reduce makes sense; otherwise, a traditional for-loop is the clearest stylistically.